# How to use projections with hibernate lucene search

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-search

I am doing hibernate lucene search .It is working fine with getting entire domain object.But my requirement is projections.It only getting single value on OneToMany associated fields.So how can I get all values of @IndexedEmbedded fields with projections.Please assists your suggestions.
The following snippet is my code

```
    @Indexed(index="Skills")
                @AnalyzerDef(name = "skillAnalyzer",
                tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
                filters = {
                  @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                  @TokenFilterDef(factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class, params = {
                    @Parameter(name = "language", value = "English")
                  })
                })
                @Entity
                @Table(name = "skills")
                public class Skills {
                    @Id
                    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
                    @Column(name = "skill_id")
                    @Field(name="skillIdPk",index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.YES)
                    private int skillId;

                    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.YES)
                    @Column(name = "skill")
                    private String skill;

                    @Column(name = "skill_type")
                    private String skillType = "default";

                    //setters & getters
                }


            @Indexed(index = "JobSeeker")
            @AnalyzerDef(name = "jobSeekerAnalyzer", tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class), filters = {
                    @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                    @TokenFilterDef(factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class, params = {
                            @Parameter(name = "language", value = "English") }) })
            @Entity
            @Table(name = "jobseeker")
            @Component
            public class JobSeeker {
                @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
                @Column(name = "jobseeker_id")
                private long jobSeekerId;

                @Column(name = "email_id", unique = true)
                private String emailId;

                @Column(name = "first_name")
                private String firstName;

                @Column(name = "middle_name")
                private String middleName;

                @Column(name = "last_name")
                private String lastName;

                @Column(name = "password")
                private String password;


                @IndexedEmbedded
                private Set<JobSeekerSkills> jobSeekerSkills = new HashSet<JobSeekerSkills>();
            //setters & getters


            }


        @Indexed(index="JobSeekerSkills")
        @AnalyzerDef(name = "jobseekerSkillAnalyzer",
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory=StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = {
          @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
          @TokenFilterDef(factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class, params = {
            @Parameter(name = "language", value = "English")
          })
        })
        @Entity
        @Table(name="jobseeker_skills")

        public class JobSeekerSkills 
        {
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
            @Column(name="jobseeker_skill_id")
            private long jobSeekerSkillId;

            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name="jobseeker_jobseeker_id")
            private JobSeeker jobSeeker;

            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name="skills_skill_id")
            @IndexedEmbedded
                private Skills skills;


        //setters & getters

        }

//=======================================================================
//This is my Dao code
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
        fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(JobSeeker.class).get();
        Query query = null;
        for (String string : skills) {
            query = qb.keyword().onField("jobSeekerSkills.skills.skillIdPk").matching(Integer.parseInt(string)).createQuery();
        }
        org.hibernate.search.FullTextQuery query1 =
                fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, JobSeeker.class);
            query1.setProjection("jobSeekerId", "jobSeekerSkills.skills.skill");
            List results = query1.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                Object[] object = (Object[]) results.get(i);
                System.out.println(object[0]);
                System.out.println(object[1]);
            }
        //  List<Skills> authorName1 = (List<Skills>) firstResult[1];
        //  System.out.println(authorName1);
        return results;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Hibernate Search documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#projections):

> projection does not work on collections or maps which are indexed via @IndexedEmbedded

So in your case, trying to project on `jobSeekerSkills.skills.skill`, with `jobSeekerSkills` being a collection indexed via `@IndexedEmbedded`, is not a good idea.

I'd like to point out that, since you're only performing a keyword query on a numeric field, you'd probably be better off just doing a classic JQPL/SQL query using Hibernate ORM.

Anyway, if for whatever reason you *really* want to use Hibernate Search for this, judging from your query, you don't need to project on a collection. Instead, just add an `@IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = "includePaths")` to the `jobSeeker` property of `JobSeekerSkills`, and then rework your query to target the index for entity `JobSeekerSkills`:

```
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
    fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(JobSeeker.class).get();
    Query query = null;
    for (String string : skills) {
        query = qb.keyword().onField("skills.skillIdPk").matching(Integer.parseInt(string)).createQuery();
    }
    org.hibernate.search.FullTextQuery query1 =
            fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, JobSeeker.class);
        query1.setProjection("jobSeeker.jobSeekerId", "skills.skill");
        List results = query1.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            Object[] object = (Object[]) results.get(i);
            System.out.println(object[0]);
            System.out.println(object[1]);
        }
    //  List<Skills> authorName1 = (List<Skills>) firstResult[1];
    //  System.out.println(authorName1);
    return results;
```

Note: the `includePaths` on the new `@IndexedEmbedded` is only necessary because you already have an `@IndexedEmbedded` on the reverse side of the association (`JobSeeker.jobSeekerSkills`); it avoids infinite recursion (JobSeeker.jobSeekerSkills.jobSeeker.jobSeekerSkills.jobSeeker.jobSeekerSkills...). If you remove the  `@IndexedEmbedded` on `JobSeeker.jobSeekerSkills`, then you can also remove the `includePaths` on the new `@IndexedEmbedded`.

Comment: I solved above problem.But now also, I am getting same error like what I mentioned in the post.I am not getting jobseeker all skills it only giving single skill for each jobseeker . Even though associated with multiple skills it is giving single record like one-to-one.Is their any way to get all values of Indexembedded  entity using Hibernate lucene projections??

Comment: No, you cannot have a list of tuples containing the job seeker id and a collection of skills a result of your full text query. The best you can get is a list of tuples containing the job seeker id and one of its skills, and then you'll have to post process this to group the skills by job seeker id. If that's not what you want, like I said above, you'd better use simple JPQL/HQL queries, since you don't need full-text search in this particular case.