# Hibernate Search: Store List of Children and retrieve via projection

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have the following 2 classes with hibernate and hibernate search annotations:

**Parent Class:**

```
@Indexed
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name="parent_id")
    private Long id;

    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    private String name;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", targetEntity = Child.class)
    private List<Child> childList;

    //getters and setters
}
```

**Child Class:**

```
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Parent.class)
    @ContainedIn
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    private String name;
}
```

I created an index for the above scenario. Now I am trying to get all the child names by searching a given parent name.

I used projection on the field as follows:

```
Query searchQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onField("name").matching("test").createQuery();
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(searchQuery, Parent.class);
fullTextQuery.setProjection("childList.name");
```

Now when I try to run the query to retrieve the search results, I am getting the name of only first child of the parent model.

When I see the indexes using Luke, I am able to see all the values in the document.

How to get the list of all the child names stored in index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use projections with hibernate lucene search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370523/how-to-use-projections-with-hibernate-lucene-search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example you have a model which required "turning around".

Your goal is to query a list *child names* so you need to search for the `Child` entity.

You can still include the "parent's name" in each child, and restrict your query on that.

```
@Entity @Indexed
public class Child {
...


Query searchQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onField("parent.name").matching("test").createQuery();
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(searchQuery, Child.class);
fullTextQuery.setProjection("name");
```